# run openshift redhat mean stack application in locally?

Tags: node.js, openshift, mean-stack, mean.io, openshift-enterprise

```
Building mean stack application through openshift redhat .
```

i cloned entire project into my local system. 
i am trying to run locally the entire project but i am facing the issue of connect to mongoD

[image]

Can you please tell me that how can i start project locally?

Comment: You cloned what from where?

Comment: Through Tortoisegit cloned entire meanstack application which is exist in openshift redhat

Answer (score 0):

You have to install all of the project's dependencies. The easiest way to do that is by using NPM from the command line.

Go to your projects root directory, and run the following command:

```
npm install
```

There's a bunch of other things that need to be done. In order to run this locally. You should really read the documentation on the project's Git page:

https://github.com/linnovate/mean-on-openshift/blob/master/README.md